# Return statement confusion inside find helper method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
var posts = [{
       id: 1,
       title: 'new post'
   },
   {
       id: 2,
       title: 'old post'
   }

];

var comment = {
   postId: 1,
   content: 'Great Post'
};

function postForComment(posts, comment) {
   return posts.find(function(post) {
       return post.id === comment.postId

   });
}

var c = postForComment(posts, comment);

console.log(c);
```

In the above code, the output is as expected, but I am unable to understand the usage of the return statement inside the function `postForComment`. Why is it using two return functions and which return function is going where?

Comment: Outer one is for `postForComment`, inner one is for `find`

Comment: by saying outerone ,you mean to say var c=postForComment(posts,comment);

Comment: Yes, outer one is the value that goes into `c`.

Comment: `return` always returns to the most immediate surrounding function block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, each `function` needs to return its result, and here there are two, nested.

The `postForComment` returns its result with

```
return posts.find(...)
```

But also inside `posts.find` is a `function`, which also need to return its result.

```
function(post) {
  return post.id === comment.postId
}
```

So if the `function` inside `posts.find` (generally called a *callback function*) doesn't return anything, `postForComment` won't have anything to return either.

Answer (score 1):

```
posts.find(function(post){
  return post.id===comment.postId
 });
```

You can consider the above code snippet to be independent. In this case  this function will return the value of `post` which satisfied `post.id === comment.postId`.

The returned value is received by the function `postForComment`. The first return value inside `postForComment` will in turn pass this value to the variable `c`

```
function postForComment(posts,comment){
 return posts.find(function(post){
  return post.id===comment.postId
 });
}
```

In this code snippet there are two functions. The second `return` statement returns the value of the first post value that satisfies the condition. in `posts.find`, each value of posts is passed to the function as the variable post. When the condition is satisfied the function inside will return the value of the post that satisfied the condition `post.id === comment.postId`. The first `return` statement is so that the value that is returned by `posts.find` is returned to the caller of the function. That is the variable c will receive the value that is returned by `posts.find`

Answer (score 0):

[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function accepts a callback function, in your case the callback function is

```
function(post) {
       return post.id === comment.postId
 }
```

So the inner `return` is the return from that `callback` function  & the outer return is the return from the `postForComment` function

Answer (score 0):

The first return in postForComment make this function returning the value found in posts.
The return inside the callback function passed to posts.find is here because array.prototype.find expects a callback that returns true or false

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of your code is shown below. The `find()` function iterates on all the `posts` and calls `compareIDs()`, passing the current post as a parameter.

When `compareIDs()` returns true, `find` will stop iterating and return the current post, which will get stored in `matchingPost`.

Now `matchingPost` will be returned from `postForComment()` and get stored in `c`.

HTH

```js
var posts = [{
       id: 1,
       title: 'new post'
   },
   {
       id: 2,
       title: 'old post'
   }

];

var comment = {
   postId: 1,
   content: 'Great Post'
};

function postForComment(posts, comment) {
   var matchingPost = posts.find(function compareIDs(post) {
       return post.id === comment.postId

   });
   return matchingPost;
}

var c = postForComment(posts, comment);

console.log(c);
```